# How to get access to the firestore id property in the map method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm passing my firebase firesotre document id to another component. I need to have access to the id of certain document. I've used `doc.id` in the `key` prop, but It happened that I can't access the that `key` prop in the other component. it says `undefined`.

Here's the maping method

```
db.collection("books")
      .orderBy("added", "desc")
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
        setBooksNewAdded(
          snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, book: doc.data() }))
        )
      );
```

Here's how I'm rendering the data

```
{booksNewAdded.map(({ id, book }, index) => {
                      if (index <= 20) {
                        return (
                          <SideContentBooks
                            key={id}
                            imageUrl={book.imageUrl}
                            name={book.name}
                            author={book.author}
                            added={book.added}
                          />
                        );
                      }
```

I know that the `key` prop is needed as each individual element should have a unique key, but I do need to get access the key in my component.